# Try Ubuntu works great, does it mean when I install it on the HDD, it will work the same way?

Tags: boot, hard-drive, hp

I have an HP Notebook Laptop and I want to install Ubuntu on the HDD.

I bought an SSD and cloned the contents of HDD to it. The Windows OS seems to be working very well on the SSD, so I was wondering if I can install Ubuntu on the HDD for learning purposes, while having the SSD as my fall back when I need Windows.

I did not get much help from HP Support Forum, and searching a bit, I found that Ubuntu has a love/hate relationship with HP laptops. So, I created a bootable USB with LTS ubuntu, and try to run it.

I was extremely surprised to see how well it ran. It did heat up my CPU, though. I checked if the drivers were working, and the Ubuntu was able to work with Wifi(which does not work on Windows), sound was okay, display was okay, brightness was adjustable.

All in all, everything I could think of checking was working fine. So, I was wondering if it will work the same way if I install it permanently on my HDD, and should I go ahead with it. If there are some caveats I don't know about, please help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: It will run as least as well, possibly even better, as a HDD install will be faster than a USB install (because of the speed of the medium). Also, the installation procedure, when run while connected to the Internet, will be able to pick up the latest software updates. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply. It does answer my question.

Comment: Consider creating a partition in the SSD and installing Ubuntu there. It would be much faster than the HDD installation.

Answer (score 0):

That is the main purpose of the live session: being able to run the operating system on your hardware without proceeding to a definitive install, so you can check how it runs, whether wifi is supported, etc. before installing.

Installing an operating system on SSD is certainly recommended: that ensures quick starting and quick loading of applications, and an overall perception of more speed than when you install on a traditional drive.